# How to give write access to first user who came online using firebase rules?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a data structure like this in Firebase Realtime DB

```
-Space
   --$spaceID
       --name
       --created
       -- data : {
           --name
           --created
       }
       --online_users : {
           $userid : true
       }
```

I want only single user to be able to have write access inside "data" Object who is currently inside online_user object and only single user should be present inside online_user. How to write Firebase rule for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please add your complete rules so we can see how it's setup.  remember that realtime rules cascade, so i'm not sure if you have anything above -Space. As an example(not knowing your complete use case) Under data, you can add $uid, then add the name and created to that

--  "data"  {

-- "$userid" : {

-- ".write": "auth.uid == $userid"

}
}

Comment: Currently it is all public